# Is there a way to simulate socket failure in Java?

Tags: java

I was wondering if there was a way to simulate socket failure in TCP Java , without actually shutting down a socket/force-shutting down that socket side.

This would be using TCP, and the program would be part of a larger app, where we attempt to demonstrate some failsafe ability (i.e, after we shutdown the client, we'd recover state somehow.

For example, if we have a simple Echo Server/Client pair ; is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Using a mock framework, yes, probably; now it depends on how your code is structured.

Comment: The question is unclear: Is this for testing? Or is this supposed to be part of the program's functionality somehow? What kind of socket do you want to "disrupt", and what effect do you intend this to have? Best show some code to give context.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You can manually call `Socket.close()` to close a socket which will close its streams as well. For more complex simulations, extend `Socket` and override its streams with custom implementations. Basically, wrap the socket and its streams in a layer you can then use to produce exceptions / communication errors.

Comment: @RealSkeptic  - the context is that we want to have a system that demonstrates some "failsafe" ability - so there will be a SocketMonitor, and we want to show that we can restart a socket that has been shut-down, thus keeping the client/socket pairing alive.   So - I think we'll need an `AppMonitor` class, maybe a `JVMMonitor` too

Answer (score 0):

I know that lots of time past since 2015 - maybe I'll help someone else

if your process waiting on the accept()
You can set a timeout on the socket

```
socket.setSoTimeout(<timeout in milliseconds>);
```

This would trigger SocketTimeoutException when the timeout would expire